# C macros: Conditional code based on parameter value?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is there a cleaner/simpler way to do this?

The below works OK, but I think it's ugly - I'd like a solution that doesn't need a separate #define for every possible invalid value passed as "port".

```
#define _port_A_config_digital(mask)        // do nothing; this port is always digital
#define _port_B_config_digital(mask)        AD1PCFGSET = (mask)
#define _port_C_config_digital(mask) 
#define _port_D_config_digital(mask) 
#define _port_E_config_digital(mask)
#define _port_F_config_digital(mask) 
#define _port_G_config_digital(mask)
#define _port_H_config_digital(mask) 
#define _port_I_config_digital(mask) 
#define _port_J_config_digital(mask) 
#define _port_K_config_digital(mask) 

#define ConfigDigitalBits(port, mask)      _port_##port##_config_digital(mask)
```

If "port" is *anything* other than B, I want a null statement.

I'd like to get rid of all the #defines other than the one that does something.

I want to do this because on this MCU all ports other than B are *always* digital and there's nothing to be done.

But calling ConfigDigitalBits() ought to be a valid thing to do for *any* port.

Comment: If port is a variable that is evaluated at runtime, then ConfigDigitalBits(port, mask) can't reduce to a null statement because there would at a minimum need to be runtime code to test whether port == B. If I'm misunderstanding what you're looking for, please clarify your question.

Comment: @sifferman: Guess I wasn't clear, sorry. This actually works, it's just ugly. The idea is that I want to test  at compile time if the passed parameter "port" is 'B'.  The passed parameter will always be a constant token (but not always the same constant token - could but A, B, C .. K).

Comment: I can't think of a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
#define CONFIG_DIGITAL_BITS(PORT, MASK) \
  do { if (PORT == 'B') AD1PCFGSET = (MASK); } while (0)
```

and trust (or check by reading the assembly) your compiler to evaluate the `if` condition at compile-time.  That is,

```
CONFIG_DIGITAL_BITS('B', 0x42);
```

would generate code for only

```
AD1PCFGSET = 0x42;
```

and

```
CONFIG_DIGITAL_BITS('A', 0x42);
```

would generate no code at all.

The proposed code above has the problem that it ignores errors.  For example,

```
CONFIG_DIGITAL_BITS('Z', 0x42);
```

would happily compile although there is no port `Z`.  You could `assert` on this but this will only catch the error at run-time.

Once you got to this, consider getting rid of the macro at whole and use an `inline` function instead that will also permit constant propagation.

```
inline void
config_digital_bits(const char port, const unsigned mask)
{
  assert(port >= 'A' && port <= 'K');
  if (port == 'B')
    AD1PCFGSET = mask;
}
```